# How to set HADOOP_CLASSPATH via oozie while running HBase job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, oozie

I'm using CDH5. I'm hit by a HBase bug while running a MapReduce job through Oozie in a fully distributed environment. This job connects to HBase and adds records programmatically.  Requesting to refer these links to understand the bug I'm hitting. Please note that I cannot modify the map reduce job code. The job runs fine from commandline after setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH env variable. But there seem to be no way to set/override this environment variable from oozie. As a result the job fails when running from oozie. Anybody experienced and found a workaround for this problem?

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.1/bk_releasenotes_hdp_2.0/content/ch_relnotes-hdpch_relnotes-hdp-2.0.9.0-knownissues-hbase.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11118

Answer (score 0):

You can set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH in the system that runs oozie server.  So,  sending it every time in request is not required. 
Otherwise,  we can set it in the xml. In file oozie-site.xml set:

```
<property>

    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.hadoop.configurations</name>
    <value>*=/home/user/oozie/etc/hadoop</value>
</property>
```

Where /home/user/oozie/etc/hadoop is the absolute path where hadoop
configuration files are located.

Comment: Setting the env variable in the machines does not help. It gets overwritten. The problem is because of this bug the /etc/hbase/conf and hbase-protocol jar must be loaded before other jars are loaded. They should be the first entried in the classpath.